# Preserving hyperlinks in MS Word text boxes when saving to PDF

Tags: pdf, hyperlink, ms-word

I have several textboxes that are hyperlinked to other areas of my document, but when I save it to a PDF, the hyperlinks are not preserved. I have tested many different scenarios, and hyperlinks for inline text, images, and text in the text boxes are preserved but not hyperlinks created for the text box object itself. Is there any workaround to have the hyperlink for the text box object be preserved when the Word file is saved to a PDF? I am open to anything up to and including using VBA. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Word 2010, your problem may be solved by first saving your document in the Word 97-2003 format, and then saving as a PDF.

See this link for more: [Word 2010 Image Hyperlink Issue](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/eeca6ad7-b9d9-403c-9777-532979a70cc1/word-2010-save-to-pdf-or-xps-loses-hyperlinks-on-images?forum=word)

Answer (score 0):

The "usual" way to retain hyperlinks when creating PDF is using Acrobat and the PDFMaker macros which come with Acrobat.

They say that the PDF creation tool coming with Word does have limitations.